# Android : Unable to update document fields in Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to perform two operations in a database transaction.

- Adding a new document in Collection A. This is successful
- updating the fields of an existing document in Collection B. This fails

Also checked that success listener is called as well yet document fields are not updated. The path of document reference is also correct.

```
database.runTransaction((Transaction.Function<Void>) transaction -> {

            message.createdAt = new Timestamp(new Date()); // just to be safe if the UI is not creating this.

            collRef.add(ModelMapper.prepareMessageModel(message)).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {

             // Added a new document in collection A

            });

            CollectionReference collRefConf = composer.composeConversationCollectionReference(conversationRequest);
            collRefConf.get(Source.SERVER).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                        // Updating an existing document in collection B

                        ConversationConfigRequest configRequest = new ConversationConfigRequest(message.conversationDocumentId,
                                document.getId());

                        DocumentReference configDocReference = composer.composeConversationConfigDocumentReference(configRequest);

                        configDocReference.update(
                                FirestoreConstants.ConversationProperties.ConversationConfig.LAST_MESSAGE, message.message
                        )
                                .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                                    Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, "onSuccess: ");

                                })
                                .addOnFailureListener(e -> Log.d(Config.LOGTAG, "onFailure: "+e));
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                Log.d("", "pullConversationConfigId: ");
            });

            return null;
        });
```

Comment: Seems like the update is not working... What are those classes `ConversationConfigRequest` and 'FirestoreConstants.ConversationProperties.ConversationConfig'? Is this a framework or your on project?

Comment: These are my project classes. FirestoreConstants.ConversationProperties.ConversationConfig.LAST_MESSAGE contains the key where I am trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

If the whole object will be changed, you could try using set so the whole document is updated. Also try using an OncompleteListener instead of onSuccessListener to see if the task is being completed

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection().document(id)
    .set(yourObject).addOnCompleteListener{/*your code after completion here*/}
```

Comment: Tried it just now. Still doesn't update the document fields in firestore. Listener returns true for task.isSuccessful()